# c++ use shared_ptr to 2-d array of unknown size as input to function

Tags: arrays, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement Dijkstras algoritm on a map consisting of tiles (i.e. an area of 6x6 m consisting of 40x40 cm blocks who are acessible or walls) and to do that i need to calculate the distance between two tiles.
I have created two classes `Tile` and `Dij_Tile` where the `Tile` `class` is the actual/physical tile containing position etc. and `Dij_Tile` `class` contains a `shared_ptr` to it's `Tile` representative aswell as reach cost etc.

I have in my test file(using `catch.hpp` to create a test file) an array with all the tiles (called `all_tiles_test`) which is an 2-d array containing all the tiles.

Thereafter I create a pointer(`shared_ptr`) to this array (called `all_tiles_test_ptr`).

After that I want to send `all_tiles_test_ptr` to a function who calculate the distance between two tiles.
The problem is I don't know how to declare the input to the function where the input is a shared_ptr to an 2-d array of unknown(at the time of coding) size. How should i do that?

Declarations in the test file:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Tile> all_tiles_test[2][2];
 auto all_tiles_test_ptr(all_tiles_test);
```

The function, which lies in another file (Tile_Distance .h and .cc):

```
double tile_dist(std::shared_ptr<Dij_Tile> start_dij_tile_ptr,
     std::shared_ptr<Dij_Tile> end_dij_tile_ptr,
     std::shared_ptr<???> all_tiles_ptr);
```

where ??? is the part I don't know how to implement.

Comment: The type of `all_tiles_test_ptr` is `std::shared_ptr<Tile> (*)[2]`, if that's what you are asking - a (plain, dumb) pointer to an array of two `std::shared_ptr<Tile>`.

Comment: I tried that but got the following error from the compiler:
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
   std::array<Tile> (*)[2]


I tried with argument ´std::shared_ptr<Tile, Tile> all_tiles_ptr but it didn't do it´

Comment: I don't understand the nature of your problem. Anyway, [this compiles for me](http://rextester.com/YJPFO65737). Hope it helps.